# From non static to static

Tags: android, static, non-static

Trying to make an intent happens from a fragment to next activity, apparently this error shows up at goMakan(); and goMakan1(); . This is something new to me and have no idea how to fix it. I'm sorry if it's a duplicate question.

```
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView picture;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;

        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false));

            picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);

            final Button button[] = new Button[2];

            for (int h = 0; h < button.length; h++) {
                final int b = h;
                button[h].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        button[0] = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
                        button[1] = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
                        if (button[b] == button[0]) {
                            goMakan();
                        } else if (button[b] == button[1]) {
                            goMakan1();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }



        public void goMakan() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Malis.Activity);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void goMakan1(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AbangBurn.Activity);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: which error????

Comment: @PriyeshKumar non-static cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Don't apologize for posting a duplicate. Instead make an effort to at least just Google for the error message and you would have found hundreds if not thousands of duplicates on this website alone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a static anything from a static something.  They either both have to be static, or not.

Last time I ran into this, I duplicated the static method as a non-static, just so I could get to it from another part of the program that needed it non-static.